# Laravel and Carbon returning incorrect time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am populating datetime-local input field using this in my controller:

```
public function create()
    {
        $task = new Task();
        $task->start_date = Carbon::now();
        $task->due_date = Carbon::now();

        return view('tasks.create', compact('task'));
    }
```

and this in my view:

```
{!! Form::input('datetime-local', 'start_date', $task->start_date->format('Y-m-d\TH:m'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::input('datetime-local', 'due_date', $task->due_date->format('Y-m-d\TH:m'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

However, the value of the fields is always:

```
<input class="form-control" name="start_date" type="datetime-local" value="2016-05-12T22:05" id="start_date">
```

If I do a `dd($task)` in my `create()` method the attributes have the current time in.

```
#attributes: array:2 [▼
    "start_date" => Carbon {#186 ▼
      +"date": "2016-05-12 22:20:14.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "UTC"
    }
    "due_date" => Carbon {#187 ▼
      +"date": "2016-05-12 22:20:14.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "UTC"
    }
  ]
```

Trying to figure out why the input is displaying the incorrect time when the attributes have the correct time value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is:

```
Y-m-d\TH:m
```

Which means:

```
(Year to 4 digits)-(Month with Leading zeros)-(Day to 2 digits with leading zeros)T(Hours in 24 hour format):(Month with Leading zeros)
```

you want:

```
Y-m-d\TH:i // 'i' = minutes with leading zeros
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I can't believe I missed that! Just to correct you (sorry) 'j' is day of the month 'i' is minutes. If you edit your answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I caught that before you replied. It's fixed.